# Lettrine in lettre class make a too large left margin

Tags: spacing, letters, white-space, lettrine, lettre

### Explanations

When I use a `\lettrine` command from `lettrine` package inside the `letter` environment with `lettre` class, so, the lettrine occur a big unwanted left margin.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{lettre}
\usepackage{lettrine}


\begin{document}

  \begin{letter}{~}
    \opening{Mister,}

    \lettrine{H}{ello sir} lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et consectetur quia adipit erit et nunquam aeter 

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

### Rendering

[image: Rendering]

### Some tries

I try to use `\noindent` before `\lettrine` but it doesn’t have any effect.

**Edit.** It doesn’t work either with `\hspace{<negative value>}`.

### Question

How to avoid the big left-margin with a lettrine inside the `lettre` class?

Comment: Starting from my TeX Live 2019 the code produces the expected result. You should realize that TeX Live 2016 is severely outdated and TeX Live 2021 has been available for a few months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. Below is my picture generated from your MWE:
[image]

Comment: Strange. Could it be the version I use (XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)?

Comment: I use TeX Live 2022/dev. You might want to upgrade your TeX Live.

Comment: I can’t yet install an up to day version, but I think I can already close this tread. Can I mark it as solved?

Comment: @fauve, certainly!